# Grouping the sum of a field in the weeks of the current month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so

```
name | count | date_of_play
```

Where name is just varchar, count is an integer, and date is a mysql date.

I'm trying to collate the rows in the table by weeks in the current month, and then summing the counts of all days in each week.

Essentially, the output would look like this:

```
Week | Count
1        x
2        y
3        z
4        a
```

Where the count corresponds to the total counts that occurred in that week.
Naturally, there might not always be 4 weeks to show, since we won't always be at the end of the current month.

currently, my sql query is

```
Select WEEK(`date_of_play`) Week, SUM(`count`) as Count FROM  table 
WHERE 
WEEK(date_of_play) > (WEEK(CURDATE()-4))
GROUP BY
    WEEK(`date_of_play`) ORDER by MIN(`date_of_play`)
```

And this isn't returning any results.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How are you defining "weeks of the current month"?

Comment: 1st - 7th : Week 1
8th-15th: Week 2
16th: 23rd: Week3
23rd onwards : Week4
But this is a loose definition really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic needs to be fixed to subtract "4" from the week.  This will at least return results:

```
SELECT WEEK(date_of_play) as Week, SUM(count) as Count
FROM table 
WHERE WEEK(date_of_play) >= WEEK(CURDATE()) - 4
GROUP BY WEEK(date_of_play)
ORDER by MIN(date_of_play);
```

To get data for the current month, the logic should be more like:

```
SELECT WEEK(date_of_play) as Week, SUM(count) as Count
FROM table 
WHERE date_of_play >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (1 - DAY(CURDATE())) DAY
GROUP BY WEEK(date_of_play)
ORDER by MIN(date_of_play)
```